# How do I correctly iterate using Outer when an argument / slot is a nested list?

Tags: functions, date-and-time, functional-style, time-series, iteration

I have the following complex nested iteration situation.

- I begin with a list, `data`, that comprises 16 TemporalData objects
- Each TemporalData object contains 2 paths. Let's call them `v` and `r`. They have a common date index, so the date paths in each path are both the same length.

[image]

- I partition each of the paths in the TemporalData objects in `data` into 20 day periods, offset by 1 / overlapping by 19.

```
partitionedSets = 
  Partition[#, 20, 1]& /@ data[[#]]["DatePaths"] & /@ Range @ Length @ data;
```

- `partitionedSets` now contains 16 lists of 2 lists (representing `v` and `r`) that vary in length as follows. `vLengths` and `rLengths` will always return the same values

```
vLengths = Length @ partitionedSets[[#, 1]] & /@ Range @ 16

(*{216, 216, 215, 214, 213, 212, 212, 212, 211, 210, 209, 208, 207,
207, 207, 206}*)
```

- The output of the first list of `partitionedSets` looks like this:

> ```
> partitionedSets[[1, All, 1]]
> ```

[image]

- Now, for each of the 16 lists of `v` and `r` series, I want to create a Date indexed set of "zipped together" ordered pairs of `v` and `r`. This is easy enough to do manually. For example, to get the first set of `orderedPairs` from the first `partitionedSet` of the first TemporalData object in `data`:

```
orderedPairs = 
  MapThread[
    List, 
    {partitionedSets[[1, 1, 1, All, 1]], 
     Thread[{partitionedSets[[1, 1, 1, All, 2]], partitionedSets[[1, 2, 1, All, 2]]}]}]
```

[image]

The problem I have is when I attempt to gather all combinations of 16x2xn lists into lists of ordered pairs. This is because the value of `n` depends on the Length of the combination of `v` or `r` and the `partitionedSet` I am currently iterating through. I know the solution is to use `Outer` -- and I can get it to work if I arbitrarily limit `n` in this case to 200.

```
dumb = 
  Outer[
    MapThread[
      List,
      {partitionedSets[[#1, 1, #2, All, 1]],
       Thread[{partitionedSets[[#1, 1, #2, All, 2]],
       partitionedSets[[#1, 2, #2, All, 2]]}]}]&, Range @ 16, Range @ 200];
```

[image]

But what I am really trying to achieve is to make this same code work where the value for the second slot `#2` in `Outer` is dynamic / recursive (really should be something like `Range @ vlengths[[#]]& /@ Range @ Length@vLengths` — but this fails.)

So, my question is: How can I functionally create 16*n lists of `orderedPairs` where n is dynamic / nested /recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may forgo the bulk of your manipulations by using [`TimeSeriesWindow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesWindow.html).

With example 2 path time series data

```
data = TemporalData /@
  {
   FinancialData["GOOGL", {"High", "Low"}, {"2 Jan 2019", "10 Dec 2019"}]
   , FinancialData["GE", {"High", "Low"}, {"4 Jan 2019", "17 Dec 2019"}]
   }
```

Then using [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) to produce the indexed offsets and the `"Dates"` and `"PathLength"` properties of [`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) the offset partitions can be created by

```
partitioned =
  With[{ts = #, dates = #["Dates"], pathlength = #["PathLength"], windowsize = 20},
     TimeSeriesWindow[ts, dates[[#]]] & /@
      Table[{i, i + (windowsize - 1)}, {i, 1, pathlength - (windowsize - 1)}]
     ] & /@ data;
```

Varying number of partitions have been created according to each `TemporalData` object.

```
Length /@ partitioned
```

> ```
> {218, 221}
> ```

All 20 steps in length

```
DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Map[#["PathLength"] &, partitioned, {2}]
```

> ```
> {20}
> ```

with 2 paths

```
DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Map[#["PathCount"] &, partitioned, {2}]
```

> ```
> {2}
> ```

Your final form can be selected with the below. I am throwing in your `Standardize` request but not that it is best to put all requests in the original post as people don't respond well to additions. However, it is your first post so I am going to give you a break.

```
partitionedSets =
  MapAt[
   MapThread[Join,
     {
      List /@ #["Dates"]
      , List /@ Transpose@MapAt[Standardize, #["ValueList"], 1]
      }
     ] &
   , partitioned
   , {All, All}
   ];
```

Then

```
partitionedSets[[1, 1]]
```

displays your final structure for the first element of the first list with `Standardize` transform on first path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is really helpful and concise! Thank you very much for taking time to answer my question. 

As a note, if i wanted to apply a transform (say, Standardize) to /just the first path/ in each series once the partitioning into groups of 20 had occurred, what would you recommend? TimeSeriesThread?

As this answers the broad question I will mark this as answered. Thank you again for your time and assistance!

Comment: Sorry, I missed something in my original comment and then I couldn't edit in time.  Two things: (1) if i wanted to apply a transform (say, Standardize) to /just the first path/ in each series once the partitioning into groups of 20 had occurred, what would you recommend? TimeSeriesThread?
(2) to answer this fully the final step is to convert each timeseries of two paths into a list of ordered pairs where the two values in each path are threaded together and combined with the common date index. ie {{Date(i),{v(i),r(i)},{Date(j),{v(j),r(j)}}. That's the part I'm really stuck on! Thank you!

Comment: @R110 See update.